# ¿Dónde podemos hacer memes del SE o podemos al menos hacerlo?

Tags: discusión

A veces veo cosas interesantes en el SE que me llaman la atención, por ejemplo preguntas relacionadas con otras, usuarios que se destacan.

En este caso para mí es la reciente obsesión de [Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie) por las drogas.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con _usuarios reluciendo_?

Comment: Creo que el chat puede ser un buen lugar para este tipo de coñas. Lo frecuenta gente muy sana y hay buen ambiente, así que algo desenfadado puede entrar bien.

Comment: @fedorqui - Quizás quiere decir *usuarios que se destacan*.

Answer (score 3):

Tú verás que por descubrir un filón de preguntas que me parecieron interesantes me van a tachar de [drogata](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17342/12637)... :-D No, ya en serio, si quieres hacer memes el mejor sitio es el chat, sin duda. Aunque sí es cierto que algunos sitios han publicado preguntas en sus sitios Meta para hacer recopilación, como en [ELU](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6852/280768), [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2188) y [otros](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/350184).

En todo caso, creo que las respuestas que se dan en esos sitios dan que pensar un poco acerca de lo que realmente es un meme. Un meme no es un hecho puntual que te haya podido hacer más o menos gracia, como mi obsesión con las drogas (como comentas), y que de ahí saques una imagen con un texto arriba y otro abajo haciendo una broma. Eso no es el meme. El meme es la capacidad que tiene esa imagen para hacerse viral y recorrer todo Internet pasando de mano en mano. Eso es el meme: el trozo de información que se hace popular.

Fíjate en las respuestas de ejemplo: ninguna tiene imágenes. Los ejemplos son del tipo "alguien hace una broma o dice algo gracioso o lo que sea, y la gente lo adopta como parte de su cultura y la broma se hace recurrente". Uno que me hace especial gracia que se usa mucho en el sitio de [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) es el de "un 4 tachado sigue siendo un 4". Allí por la particularidad del sitio de ir poniendo respuestas e ir mejorándolas se van tachando los resultados previos. Si alguien tenía una respuesta de 44 bytes y la deja en 42 se verá así:

## <strike>44</strike> 42 bytes

Como ves, hay poca diferencia entre <strike>44</strike> y 44 (aunque no lo parezca, el primero está tachado y el segundo no). Esto hizo gracia y cada vez que alguien intenta tachar un 4 aparece un comentario diciendo que "un 4 tachado sigue siendo un 4". Eso es el meme: el que la gente adopte esa información como parte de su cultura y haga perdurar en el tiempo la broma. Mi obsesión por las drogas puede haber hecho gracia, pero si dentro de un mes se ha olvidado, no es un meme. Fíjate en la definición del Merriam-Webster de [meme](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meme):

> an idea, behavior, style, or usage that spreads from person to person within a culture

Así pues, si quieres poner una imagen graciosa sobre ese hecho puntual, por favor, siéntete libre de hacerlo y publícala en [el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia). Una pregunta recopilatoria sobre memes (que podemos plantear aquí perfectamente) debería tener como respuestas auténticos memes, como los que se exponen en los sitios enlazados arriba.

Comment: Vaya, que tenemos que insistir e insistir en el tema de tu relación con las drogas hasta conseguir que se haga viral :P (¡muy buena respuesta!)

Comment: Y no nos olvidemos de aquél relato de ciencia ficción que estabas escribiendo cuando preguntaste por el [opuesto etimológico de "feminismo"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24450/5481). No te hagas el sueco. Sabemos que lo estas escribiendo a pachas con Pérez-Reverte, que tú ya tienes "linea directa"...

Comment: @walen - ¿Podrías dar el contexto, por favor?  Yo quiero entender esta frase "a lo @fedorqui" también.  Pero fui al enlace que pusiste y no me ayudó para nada -- creo me falta contexto.

Comment: Charlie, ¿tienes acaso una falta de dedo con "hay poca diferencia entre 44 y 44"?

Comment: @aparente001 no, ningún error. Cómo explico, el primer 44 está tachado y el segundo no. Fíjate bien. :-)

Comment: estoy altamente tentado a tomar la imagen de charly y editarla para montarle un cigarrillo